# Datatable width mismatching while using scrollX: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm generating jquery dataTable , I'm able to do so but the width of header and rows is mismatching ,
I find out this is happening due to scrollx: true. I'm using the below code:

```
    this.dtOptions = {
        destroy: true,
        pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
        pageLength: 10,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        ordering: false,
        data: this.dataTable['rows'],
        columns: this.dataTable['columns'],
        scrollX : true,
    }
```

By the following code I'm getting the dataTable
[as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uotL2.png)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? If we cannot recreate your problem, it may be harder to help you.

Comment: Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask].